# Why did the OpenAI's scaling law paper underestimate the importance of data in model scaling?

Tags: machine-learning, llm

The Chinchilla paper (Hoffmann, Jordan, et al. "[Training compute-optimal large language models](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.15556)." arXiv preprint arXiv:2203.15556 (2022).) famously found that when scaling a model, you should roughly increase your parameter count and data amount equally, as opposed to the earlier OpenAI scaling law paper which said you should increase your parameter count by substantially more than your data amount.

On page 3, the Chinchilla paper gives the following explanation for why the OpenAI paper made this mistake:

> First, the authors use a fixed number of training tokens and learning rate schedule for all models; this
> prevents them from modelling the impact of these hyperparameters on the loss. In contrast, we find
> that setting the learning rate schedule to approximately match the number of training tokens results
> in the best final loss regardless of model size—see Figure A1. For a fixed learning rate cosine schedule
> to 130B tokens, the intermediate loss estimates (for ' << 130B) are therefore overestimates of the
> loss of a model trained with a schedule length matching '. Using these intermediate losses results in
> underestimating the effectiveness of training models on less data than 130B tokens, and eventually
> contributes to the conclusion that model size should increase faster than training data size as compute
> budget increases.

But why should this be the case? If your learning rate schedule leads to overestimating the loss for smaller amounts of training data, shouldn't that lead you to overestimate the effect of data on loss and thus recommend increasing data size quicker than parameter count instead of the other way around?